# Find the determinant of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $f,g \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ where $E$ is a complex vector space of dimension $n$, verifying :

$$ f \circ g-g \circ f = f$$

I need to determine $\det(f)$.

I wrote that  $\det(f \circ (g-Id_E)) = \det(g\circ f)$ therefore $\det(f) \det(g-Id_E) = \det(g) \det(f)$ and consequently : $\det(f) = 0$ or $\det(g-Id_E) = \det(g)$.

How can I conclude?

Comment: Do you know how to write $g$ as a triangular matrix?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, you may still find that idea helpful but the method I was going for will not solve the problem.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop No problem for the double comment. Do you mean using the fact that $\det(g) = \displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^r \lambda_i$ where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ are the eigenvalues of $g$?

Comment: Yes I was thinking to compare $det(g)$ and $det(g - id)$ using that formula, but it's not as fruitful as I thought, as taking $g$ to be the diagonal matrix with $1/2$ on the diagonal has the same determinant as $g - id$ when $n$ is even. Putting $f$ in, say, Jordan canonical form may still help but I'm not confident in any particular approach.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop That's right, I noticed that we can even have $\det(g-Id_E) = \det(g) = \det(g+Id_E)$ because if $\{-1,0,1\}$ are all eigenvalues of $g$ then $\det(g-Id_E) = \det(g) = \det(g+Id_E) = 0$... That question is surprisingly harder than I expected, because in my problem I have shown later that the only eigenvalue of $f$ is $0$ therefore $\det(f) = 0$.

Comment: I cannot find a simple reason why $\det(f) = 0$...

Comment: Yeah I can't find a reason at the moment. How did you show that the only eigenvalue of $f$ is $0$?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop It was part of the whole exercise, first of all they asked about $\mathrm{Tr}(f)$ and $\det(f)$ then I had to show that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we had $f^k \circ g - g \circ f^k = k f^k $, I could deduce from that the fact that $\mathrm{Tr}(f^k) = 0$ forall $k$. In the end given $\lambda_1, \dots\, \lambda_p$ the distinct eigenvalues of $f$ I had to show that $p= 1$, I have shown that if $p\geq 2$ then we had a contradiction using a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Indeed I had $\mathrm{Tr}(f^k) =  \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^p m(\lambda_i) \lambda_i^k =0 $ where $m(\lambda_i)$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ as an eigenvalue of $f$. Finally $f$ had only one eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $\mathrm{Tr}(f) = \lambda = 0$. Which proves *afterwards* that $\det(f) = 0$.

Comment: In any case, I have come up with a solution to why $\det f = 0$ and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that $\det f = 0$. If this was not that case, then $f$ would be invertible. Multiply the equation $fg - gf = f$ on the left by $f^{-1}$ to get $g - f^{-1} g f = id$. Hence, $g = f^{-1} g f + id = f^{-1} (g + id) f$. This means that $g$ and $g + id$ are similar but this cannot hold. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $g$ iff $\lambda + 1$ is an eigenvalue of $g + id$, so $g$ and $g + id$ have different eigenvalues. For instance, take the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $g$ with the largest real part. Then $\lambda + 1$ is an eigenvalue of $g + id$ but not of $g$. Thus, $g$ and $g + id$ cannot be similar so $\det(f) = 0$

Comment: Thanks for your time. I haven't thought of using similarity, it's convenient.

Comment: Glad I could help!